# Application fails when trying to read data with debugger

Tags: c#, debugging

I have a hierarchical model of five object levels. So each object level contains a list of sub-level objects. when I seat a break point and step over with debugger to read the data from the last level object, I get question marks for each property value and the application instantly closes (doesn't crash). If I try to use these property values somewhere else in the application, then I get the stack overflow exception. So these data definitely can't accessed, but I just don't know why. Has anyone had similar problem?

Comment: `"but I just don't know why"` - Probably because there's a stack overflow exception.  You likely have an infinite recursion somewhere.  You'll want to correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem once.
It was the object ToString() method raising an exception trying to access a null value and making everything crash.

With so little information it's actually hard to tell, just look if it's also your case

Comment: Yes, it was just stupid 'typo' in my code. i had a public property that returns itself instead of a private field with same name just not capitalized :)